# If $E(|X+Y|^p)<\infty$, then $E(|X^p|)<\infty$ and $E(|Y^p|)<\infty$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent and for some $p>0$: $E(|X+Y|^p)<\infty$, then $E(|X^p|)<\infty$ and $E(|Y^p|)<\infty$.

How can I go from $E(|X+Y|^p)<\infty$ using independence to conclude something about $X$ all alone?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/188385/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By independence, 
$$
E[|X+Y|^p]=\int\limits_{}E[|X+y|^p]\mathrm dP_Y(y).
$$
Hence, if $E[|X+Y|^p]$ is finite then $E[|X+y|^p]$ is finite for $P_Y$-almost every $y$. In particular, there exists some $y$ such that $E[|X+y|^p]$ is finite. Maybe you can finish from here.

Answer (score 0):

Use Fubini-Tonelli's theorem and the fact that if $f$ is integrable, then $|f(x)|$ is finite for almost every $x$.