# How prove $E|X|^p<\infty$ and $E|Y|^p<\infty$, if $E|X+Y|^p<\infty$

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, expected-value

> Let two random variables $X$ and $Y$ be independent of each other, for some $p>0$, we have
>   $$E|X+Y|^p<\infty$$
>   Show that
>   $$E|X|^p<\infty,\quad E|Y|^p<\infty$$

**My try:** I know Minkowski inequality

$$E|X+Y|^p \leq E|X|^p + E|Y|^p, \tag{$0<p<1$}$$

But this inequality here is not useful, so how prove it? Thank you very much!

Comment: Another proof is present here : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188385/finiteness-of-expected-values-for-independent-random-variables/188408#188408

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/398997/if-exyp-infty-then-exp-infty-and-eyp-infty.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have 
$$\iint_{\mathbb R^2}|x+y|^p\mathrm dP_X(x)\mathrm dP_Y(y)=\mathbb E|X+Y|^p\lt \infty,$$
hence for $P_Y$-almost every $y$, $\int_\mathbb R|x+y|^p\mathrm dP_X(x)<\infty$. We deduce that $\mathbb E|X|^p<\infty$ by triangular inequality. Indeed, there is a constant $C_p$ such that $|a+b|^p\leqslant C_p(|a|^p+|b|^p)$, hence 
$$\int_\mathbb R|x|^p\mathrm dP_X(x)\leqslant C_p\int_\mathbb R|x+y|^p\mathrm dP_X(x)+C_p|y|^p\lt\infty$$
for a $y$ such that $\int_\mathbb R|x+y|^p\mathrm dP_X(x)\lt\infty$.

Comment: Thank you, can you post you triangular inequality? Thank you

Comment: Done now. ${}{}$

Comment: why $\int_{R}|x+y|^pdP_{X}(x)<\infty?$,second: why $\int_{R}|x|^pdP_{X}(x)\le C_{p}\int_{R}|x+y|^pdP_{X}(x)+C_{p}|y|^p?$,can you post detailed? Thank you

Comment: If a random variable has a finite integral it is finite almost everywhere. 2. I used the triangular inequality with $x=a$ and $b=-y$ then integrated.