# If $\mathbb E(|X+Y|^p) <\infty $ where $X$ and $Y$ are independent, how to prove $\mathbb E(|X|^p) < \infty$ and $\mathbb E(|Y|^p) < \infty$?

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $\mathbb E(|X+Y|^p) <\infty $ for some $p>0$, then how to prove $\mathbb E(|X|^p) < \infty$ and $\mathbb E(|Y|^p) < \infty$??

What I thought is that when $X, Y$ are independent,
$$\mathbb E(|X+Y|^p) = \mathbb E(|X|^p) + \mathbb E(|Y|^p)+ \text{extra terms},$$
so if left side is finite then right side is also finite.

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: what i thought is that when x, y are independent e(|x+y|^p) = e(|x|^p) + e(|y|^p) + extra turms. so if left side is finite then right side is also finite. @Saad

Comment: $qswesa121, Just add the detail you mentioned to the question.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference, that explain how to create latex-formatted equations in mathjax

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/618674/321264.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is not valid. By Fubini's Theorem $E|X+y|^{p} <\infty$ for some $y$ and $|X|^{p} \leq 2^{p} (|X+y|^{2}+|y|^{p})$. Hence $E|X|^{p} <\infty$.