# Bounding the $\mathbb{E}|X|^p $ and $\mathbb{E}|Y|^p$ by $\mathbb{E}|X+Y|^p$

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, expected-value

I am trying to prove the following statement:

> Let $X, Y$ be two independent random variables. If for some $p>0$, $\mathbb{E}(|X+Y|^p)<\infty$, then $\mathbb{E}(|X|^p)$ and $\mathbb{E}(|Y|^p)$ are both finite.

The trouble I am having is that all the inequalities which I can think of in this case are in the opposite direction of what I actually want to prove. For instance, Minowski's inequality allows me to conclude that
$$\mathbb{E}|X+Y|^p \leq [(\mathbb{E} |X|^p)^{1/p} +(\mathbb{E} |Y|^p)^{1/p}]^p $$,
but this is not helpful at all in terms of the direction of the inquality. I also struggled to find a way to utilize the independence assumption. I would appreciate it if someone could provide a hint.

Comment: One thing that sticks out is that if you know that any of the two expected values is finite, then the third expected value must be finite. So maybe try to prove the contrapositive that if $|X|^p, |Y|^p$ have infinite expected values then so does $|X+Y|^p$

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/398997/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/188385/321264.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $|X+Y|^p$ is integrable with respect to $\mathbb P$, we can define conditional expectation $\mathbb E[|X+Y|^p | \mathcal G]$ with respect to any $\sigma-$field $\mathcal G \subset \mathcal F$. Let $\mathcal G = \sigma(X)$ for example.

By properties of conditional expectation and independence, we get:

$$ \infty > \mathbb E[|X+Y|^p] = \mathbb E[ \mathbb E[ |X+Y|^p | \sigma(X) ] ] = \mathbb E[ H(X)] $$

Where $H(t)= \mathbb E[|t+Y|^p]$. In particular we must have $H(X) < \infty$ $\mathbb P-$almost surely, so that we need to have at least one $t \in \mathbb R$ such that $H(t) < \infty$, which means that there is some $t \in \mathbb R$ such that $\mathbb E[|t+Y|^p] < \infty$

But then $$\mathbb E[|Y|^p] = \mathbb E[ |(Y+t) + (-t)|^p] \le \Big(\big(\mathbb E[|Y+t|^p]\big)^{\frac{1}{p}} + |t| \Big)^p < \infty$$

Similarly, changing to $\sigma(Y)$ we'll get $\mathbb E|X|^p < \infty$.